# Parse textarea to return URL from content

Tags: javascript

I have `textarea` containing one or more URLs, along with other text content. I want a JavaScript function to return the text content along with the correctly formatted URL with anchor tags.

Example contents:

```
abcd http://stackoverflow.com xyz
```

I would like the function to return:

```
  abcd <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> xyz
```

What steps are needed to implement this request?

would be grateful for help.

Comment: i tried with regexp. but i couldn't succeed in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"abcd http://stackoverflow.com xyz".replace( /https?:\/\/[^ ]+/g, '<a href="$&">$&</a>')
//"abcd <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> xyz"
```