# Parse text to format URLs from content and shorten URLs

Tags: javascript

I would like to parse the following text into formatted URLs with anchor tags:

```
something is wrong with http://www.gbin1.com/index.html,  but cannot find the reason in http://www.google.com
```

How can I replace the text URLs above with `<a href="url">url</a>` and also shorten it using JavaScript as displayed below:

```
something is wrong with <a href="http://www.gbin1.com/index.html">gbin1.com</a>,  but cannot find the reason in <a href="http://www.gbin1.com">google.com</a>
```

Comment: Did you try Regular Expressions?

Comment: Why does the second link not go to Google? It seems a little sneaky to link the Google text to a non-Google site.

Comment: I try this:

function replacelinks(url){
 var pattern = /(HTTP:\/\/|HTTPS:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9.\/&?_=!*,\(\)+-]+)/i;
 var replace = "<a href=\"$1$2\">" + "$1$2".substring(0,10) + "</a>";
 return url.replace(pattern , replace); 
}

but not know how to short the url by domain name only.

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296957/parse-textarea-to-return-url-from-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution.

```
var x = "something is wrong with http://www.gbin1.com/index.html,  but cannot find the reason in http://www.google.com";
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var split = x.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i< split.length; i++){
    if(split[i].match(regex)){
        var text = split[i].split(".").slice(1).join(".").split("/")[0];

        split[i] = '<a href=\"' +split[i]+'\">'+text+'</a>';
    }
}
console.log(split.join(" "));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4JGY7/

Comment: looks good, but there is an extra comma in url as below:something is wrong with <a href="http://www.gbin1.com/index.html,">gbin1.com</a>  but cannot find the reason in <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>

Comment: Replace this line 
split[i] = '<a href=\"' +split[i]+'\">'+text+'</a>';
with

split[i] = '<a href=\"' +split[i].replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, '')+'\">'+text+'</a>';